# How to convert an int array to a nullable int array?

Tags: c#, arrays, nullable, non-nullable

Let's say I have an array containing `x` members and I want to create another array with the same Length (`x`) and the same integer values:

```
int[] arr = new int[x];
int?[] nullable_arr = arr;
```

And I can't do this:

```
int?[] arr = new int[x];
```

Is there an explicit conversion to a nullable type array or something I am not aware of?

Yes, I could simply convert each value in a loop but I'm asking if there is already an easy short way of doing this.

Comment: Any other "syntatic sugar" method will end up in looping through all items. You can use LINQ ro you can use `Array.ConvertAll`

Comment: @Fabio I think OP is indeed asking for a syntactic sugar. Why don't you post the `ConvertAll` method based answer which will be the best solution for arrays (not like the current answers which are more general, but also less efficient).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another aproach by using `Array.ConvertAll` method

```
var values = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
var nullableValues = Array.ConvertAll(ints, value => new int?(value));
```

Or with providing generic types explicitly

```
var nullableValues = Array.ConvertAll<int, int?>(ints, value => value);
```

Comment: Of course OP has chosen the shortest to type, although it's the worse from the three posted (box + unbox). +1

Comment: I was just about to ask you how to do it with the Array.Convert All and yes i really forgot about boxing and unboxing thank you

Comment: btw isnt doing this: "new int?(value)"boxing aswell?

Comment: @SuperMinefudge No. Boxing is when you convert `int` to `object`. `Cast` is doing that because it operates on `IEnumerable` (note - not `IEnumerable<int>`). So the equivalent of `Cast` is something like `arr.Select(x => (int?)(object)x)`. Btw, I'm glad you have changed your preference.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest using *Linq*:

```
 int?[] nullable_arr = arr
   .Select(item => new int?(item))
   .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`Cast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) from Linq

```
int?[] arrNull = arr.Cast<int?>().ToArray();
```